Is it possible to nest tests in xUnit.net
Testing services with kotlin + spring I usually nest my test. I think this way is powerful, especially if the service domain is quite complex. It gives the testing a natural progression and the setup of the state in the service becomes clear. The individual tests here are only dependent on the @BeforeEach methods and can be executed in any order within their nested class.
I'm now working in .NET and xUnit and I'm wondering if the same type of setup is possible here.
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD) // Makes sure all tests get it's own independent execution
class ProductApiIT {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var restTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    @Test
    fun `Should not be able to get user status without access token`() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    fun `Should not be able to create product without access token`() {
        ...
    }

    @Nested
    inner class WithAccessToken {
        lateinit var accessToken: String

        @BeforeEach
        fun `Create Access Token`() {

            ...

            accessToken = response.accessToken
        }


        @Test
        fun `Should be able to get user status`() {
            ...
        }


        @Nested
        inner class WithProduct {
            lateinit var productId: String

            @BeforeEach
            fun `Create Product`() {

                ...

                productId = response.productId
            }


            @Test
            fun `Should be able to get product`() {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}

